# How to re-scale a column by percentage change and start from a given number

Tags: python

Hei,

In my dataframe I have a column like this [4, 5, 6, ...] and would like to keep its growth rate  (0, 0.25, 0.2...) but start from 100, so that it becomes [100, 125 and 150, ...]. For every element in the new column, it is the element of the previous location in the old column * change rate from pct_change. How can I quickly do this?

```
a = pd.Series([4 ,5 , 6])
b = a.pct_change().fillna(0)
```

Then i want to make c in a way like this but this does not work.

```
c[1] = 100
for i in range(2, 5):
    c[i] = c[i-1] * (1+b[i])
```

Comment: My answer returns exactly the numbers you have mentioned in the question, but if that doesn't help, then please edit your question to clearly state what is it that you are having difficulty with.  As it stands, it doesn't provide any code showing what you have attempted.  Are you having trouble transforming the column? Or something else, either way, you need to provide [code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Yep... thats what i want. thanks!

Comment: If my response helped resolve your problem, please accept the answer

Comment: i am a new user and now able to do that, though i did!

Comment: I don't think accepting an answer to your own question is restricted for new users, maybe you are confusing it with up voting? The answer is still not accepted, maybe [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) from meta.SX is helpful. If you still can't figure it out, no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c[1] = 100
for i in range(2, 5):
    c[i] = c[i-1] * (1+b[i])
```

The way you allocate/assign to `c` is incorrect.

You first need to allocate `c` of appropriate length, then assign the first element, which is `0`, not `1`, and the loop should start from 1.  Arrays/lists in Python are 0-indexed, meaning an array of length 5 is counted from 0-4.

Try this:

```
a = pd.Series([4, 5, 6, 3, 2])

# no need for the fillna, as the first element is never used
# it is better to leave it as NaN to avoid confusion with no change
b = a.pct_change()

c = pd.Series([0] * len(a))
c[0] = 100
for i in range(1, len(a)): 
    c[i] = c[i-1] * (1+ b[i])
```

For the chosen `a`, you get the following `c`:

```
0    100
1    125
2    150
3     75
4     50
dtype: int64
```

Note that you cannot get rid of the for-loop, because your calculation has a sequential dependence (depends on the previous element); vectorisation requires every element be calculated independently.  If someone else has a vectorised solution, I would be happy to know.

Comment: hmm... not really what i meant... but thanks for tips.

Comment: you codes do return the right number for this example. but not in the way I wanted which was described in the revised question. i want to use pct_change to find the pct change between each two neighbouring elements because i always want this info...